# Coloring a label depending on color of slice and using distance

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I've been messing around with the demo code for highcharts pie charts to see if I can accomplish several things...

- Have labels inside unless the slice is too thin.  If it's too thin,
  label should be outside
- Color fonts white.  If the slice is outside or if the slice is a
  specific color, this should be black

In the below, I was able to address some of what I'm trying to do in the bottom function.  It moves labels outside based on the percentage of the slice and also colors it black.  But...

- I don't want to use attr({y:x}) for adjusting the position when the
  slice is too thin.  I would rather be able to use distance.
- I'm not sure how to check the color of a slice to then be able to color the font.  Ideally it would be something like the function
  below that uses "point" but would be for the slice instead.

Anyone know how to handle?

```
        $(function () {

            Highcharts.chart('container', {

                chart: {
                    type: 'pie'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            useHTML: true,
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            color: 'white',
                            distance: -40
                        },
                        showInLegend: true,
                    }
                },

                series: [{

                    data: [
                        ['Firefox', 45.0],
                        ['Chrome', 26.8],
                        ['IE 11', 12.8],
                        ['Edge', 8.5],
                        ['Opera', 6.2],
                        ['Other', 0.7],
                    ]
                }]
            },

            function(chartObj) {
                $.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
                    if(point.percentage < 6) {
                        point.dataLabel.css({color: 'black'}),
                        point.dataLabel.attr({y: -20})
                    }
                })
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: For the coloring, you might want to look at color:"contrast".  It does some logic to change the label to black for light colors and white for dark colors.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look.  I'm seeing just ways of adjusting the font color by checking the rgb values of the background.  Not sure how I would be able to access the color of the slice.

Comment: You can access slice's color via this.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex].color http://jsfiddle.net/duj5fd3b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your problem is to take angle of desired arc (pie slice) and calculate x and y using Math.cos and Math.sin functions.

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const series = this.series[0];
        const points = series.data;
        const chart = this;

        points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.y <= 1) {
            const myOffset = 40;
            const {x: centerX, y: centerY} = point.graphic.attr();
            const {x, y} = point.dataLabel.attr();
            const angle = point.angle;
            point.dataLabel.attr({
              x: x + Math.cos(angle) * myOffset,
              y: y + Math.sin(angle) * myOffset
            });
            point.dataLabel.css({color: 'black'});
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -25,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    innerSize: '60%',
    data: [40, 20, 20, 19, 1]
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/b1ya1x9h/

[image]